# How can I display incoming and outgoing call recordings in one listview with different symbols in android

Tags: android, listview

I am developing a application, in which incoming and outgoing calls will be recorded. I want to display incoming and outgoing call recordings in one list view and in that list view I want to show different images for incoming and outgoing because I want the user to know which is incoming and which is outgoing. So, how can I do that. Please any one can help me.

Comment: Also you have updated your question by using my answer, so you could accept it, because you have done that right things that i explained to you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199694/how-can-i-separate-incoming-and-outgoing-call-recorded-files-in-listview-in-andr/25200577#25200577

Answer (score 0):

1. In your recorded file name, you have to put this information somewhere in filename which will say where its incoming recording or outgoing.
2. keep an imgaeview indicator which will indicate either its a incoming or outgoing in your child view layout.
3. just before returing your view, decide by filename which indicator to set and put proper image indicator.

Mapping of files you can do two way --

1. Either save files like `INCOMING_XXXXX.XXX` , `OUTGOING_XXXXX.XXXX`
2. Or keep an database and there save values like

   Filename     CallType 
      XXXX         XXXX

Ofcourse first one is easy.

I guess this would be enough for implementation.